# How to add extra field after caption and title on images

Tags: media

Is there a way with Drupal that I can add more fields on the one of caption and title when uploading images?

Answer (score 0):

The [file entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) module will allow you to add fields to your files (including images) like you would with nodes.

You can then add whatever fieds you like and configure how those fields display use them in views etc.